# lubuntu reduce size of vmlinuz file for PXE boot

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, startup, pxe

I have poor knowledge about Linux systems, but Windows XP support is over.
I have two older computers. I want install Lubuntu from PXE on this computers, but the problem is that they says "NBP is too big to fit in free base memory". What should I do ? The vmlinuz file (which I think makes the problem) is around 7 MB.

Comment: might be your network hardware doesn't support boot images of that size.

Comment: it is likely. So what should I do? Lubuntu 12.04 has vmlinuz around 5 MB, and it's still to much for this computer

Comment: try to reduce your boot image or make it a two steps loader.